# $f_* f^* \mathcal{G}= \mathcal{G}$ and $f^* f_* \mathcal{F}= \mathcal{F}$ for Quasicoherent Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $f: X \to Y$ a morphism between schemes, $\mathcal{F}$ a quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_X$ module, $\mathcal{G}$ a quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_Y$ module.

My question is what are the weakest possible conditions for $f$, $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$

such that $f_* f^* \mathcal{G}= \mathcal{G}$ and $f^* f_* \mathcal{F}= \mathcal{F}$ hold? (*)

Considerations: $f^*$ and $f_*$ are connected via adjunction

$$Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(f^*\mathcal{G},\mathcal{F})= Hom_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(\mathcal{G}, f_*\mathcal{G})$$

and this gives arise for natural unit and counit trafos $\mathcal{G} \to f_* f^* \mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{F} \to f^* f_* \mathcal{F}$. But it seems that  in generally the adjunction don't provider more informations.

Does there exist a suitable theorem providing sufficent conditions for the above property (*)?

Background of my question: I want to find under which conditions the induced map $f^*: Pic(Y) \to Pic(X)$ is injective? Indeed, if I know that $f_* f^* \mathcal{G}= \mathcal{G}$ holds I get the desired injectivity.

Comment: By the projection formula $f_*(f^*G) = G \otimes f_*O_X$ so essentially you're asking for $f_*O_X = O_Y$.

Comment: @Nicolas Hemelsoet: $f_*O_X = O_Y$ is a characteristicproperty for fibrations. So the first equation holds iff $f$ is a fibration?  Does it already imply the second equation from (*)?

Comment: No, there are fibrations where $f_*O_X = O_Y$ is wrong (think when $Y$ is a point). Also there exist morphisms which are not fibrations but $f_*O_X = O_Y$. But maybe a condition could be proper irreducible fibers. 
I am not sure about the second equation.